# Android Spinner Make Item Clickable but not Selectable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-spinner

Is it possible to have an item in my spinner which is clickable but not selectable?

The scenario here is that i have a Category spinner and i want the user to input his category himself. So i want the "add Item" selection to appear at the end of the Spinner's list and make it clickable only. Can someone help ?

Comment: Just check if the selected item index is n (where n is the number of items in the list) and then swap the spinner for an EditText?

Comment: No i do not want to swap anything. Upon clicking on it, it will show a dialog. I just want the last item to be clickable so that i can open the dialog and make the last item not selectable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, in listener if you got last position by default select 0 position and do you click action whatever you want.

Comment: Yes this seems okay but when i click on it, it will be selected right ? How do i make it not selectable.

Comment: at that time you can write spinner.setSelectablePosition(0);

Answer (score 0):

```
yourSpinner?.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
               // if position == n, open dialog here 
               // and then
               yourSpinner?.setSelectablePosition(0);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like

```
    txtTimeSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if(position == last){
                txtTimeSpinner.setSelection(0);
            }else {
                //your code here for selection 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

and array first position is as default like ("Select Time")